# The sources of the zend framework package

Tags: apt, package-management

Where can I find sources that were used to build [zend-framework](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/raring/zend-framework) deb package(s)?

For most pachages there is a `.debian.tar.gz` available, but not in this case.

Where could I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/z/zend-framework/zend-framework_1.11.11-0ubuntu1.diff.gz - here is a link to the control files.

I was originally confused that it's a `diff.gz` but after that was told that it's just an old source format (ref: http://wiki.debian.org/SourcePackage#The_definition_of_a_source_package)